# How to reuse RFT scripts in RPT

Tags: rft, rpt

I have Rational Functional Tester installed on my local machine and I have written some scripts. Those RFT scripts are meant for automation and I want to import these scripts on a Rational Performance Tester.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible if you shell share them. What are you planning to do with the RFT scripts in RPT ? Run them together ? Schedule/Remote execution ? Or you just want to have all the scripts in one place ? Which protocol do you test using RPT and which app (domain) do you test using RFT ?

Comment: I will use http protocol in RPT. Actually I have RFT scripts with the same protocol. 

For automation purpose we have written RFT scripts and we want to use the same/existing scripts for performance testing also.

Answer (score 0):

*RTW Web UI Tester* comes with *RTW extensions for RFT* which allows you to run RFT scripts and RPT tests together as a part of a "Compound test".

You have to install *Rational Test Workbench Web UI Tester* shell shared with RPT and RFT. Check this video and see if it helps [Using IBM Rational Functional Tester in the Rational Test Workbench Eclipse Client](https://youtu.be/8I3me51F1ho)

The other option is to just install RPT and RFT shell shared and use the RPT custom code to invoke RFT scripts.

Comment: Thanks buddy for your suggestion. I will check on this.

Answer (score 0):

How come ?

RFT is a Functional test tool while RPT is a technical (load test) tool.

Technically, you cannot run a performance test out of an automation test.

Import is possible only between same tools and not the other way.